# torchtext BucketIterator minimum padding

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I'm trying to use the BucketIterator.splits function in torchtext to load data from csv files for use in a CNN. Everything works fine unless I have a batch that the longest sentence is shorter than the biggest filter size.

In my example I have filters of sizes 3, 4, and 5 so if the longest sentence doesn't have at least 5 words I get an error. Is there a way to let the BucketIterator dynamically set the padding for batches, but also set a minimum padding length?

This is my the code I am using for my BucketIterator:

```
train_iter, val_iter, test_iter = BucketIterator.splits((train, val, test), sort_key=lambda x: len(x.text), batch_size=batch_size, repeat=False, device=device)
```

I'm hoping there is a way to set a minimum length on the sort_key or something like that?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
FILTER_SIZES = [3,4,5]
train_iter, val_iter, test_iter = BucketIterator.splits((train, val, test), sort_key=lambda x: len(x.text) if len(x.text) >= FILTER_SIZES[-1] else FILTER_SIZES[-1], batch_size=batch_size, repeat=False, device=device)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked through the torchtext source code to better understand what the sort_key was doing, and saw why my original idea wouldn't work.

I'm not sure if it is the best solution or not, but I have come up with a solution that works. I created a tokenizer function that pads the text if it is shorter than the longest filter length, then create the BucketIterator from there.

```
FILTER_SIZES = [3,4,5]
spacy_en = spacy.load('en')

def tokenizer(text):
    token = [t.text for t in spacy_en.tokenizer(text)]
    if len(token) < FILTER_SIZES[-1]:
        for i in range(0, FILTER_SIZES[-1] - len(token)):
            token.append('<PAD>')
    return token

TEXT = Field(sequential=True, tokenize=tokenizer, lower=True, tensor_type=torch.cuda.LongTensor)

train_iter, val_iter, test_iter = BucketIterator.splits((train, val, test), sort_key=lambda x: len(x.text), batch_size=batch_size, repeat=False, device=device)
```

Answer (score 1):

Though @paul41's approach works, it's somewhat a misuse. A proper way of doing this is using `preprocessing` or `postprocessing` (before or after numericalization correspondingly). Here is an example of `postprocessing`:

```
def get_pad_to_min_len_fn(min_length):
    def pad_to_min_len(batch, vocab, min_length=min_length):
        pad_idx = vocab.stoi['<pad>']
        for idx, ex in enumerate(batch):
            if len(ex) < min_length:
                batch[idx] = ex + [pad_idx] * (min_length - len(ex))
        return batch
    return pad_to_min_len

FILTER_SIZES = [3,4,5]
min_len_padding = get_pad_to_min_len_fn(min_length=max(FILTER_SIZES))

TEXT = Field(sequential=True, use_vocab=True, lower=True, batch_first=True, 
             postprocessing=min_len_padding)
```

Nested functions required to pass parameters to inner function if those defined in the main loop (e.g. `min_length = max(FILTER_SIZES)`), but parameters can be hardcoded inside the function if this works.